# Converting LaTeX into Mathtype or MS Word format in Ubuntu

Tags: conversion, msword

I need a lot of help here, and am not sure if this is the correct place for my question - but here goes.

I am about to start (assuming I can get over this issue with software) working for a company that authors solutions and solution guides for math textbooks.

However, they do not use LaTeX, but rather MathType. I am running Lubuntu 12.04, and cannot afford to buy any software at the present. This company wants me to type up math in MathType (or TeX, then convert to MathType format), and insert the math equations and what not into a MS Word document (I believe MS Word 1997-2003 format). My contact sent me a free version of MS Office 2010 Starter software, but I have yet to be able to get it to install at all.

Additionally, I would like to not have to rely on wine and ANY windows software if at all possible. I am already having to use a trial version of MathType under Wine, but I cannot find anyway to add the MathType equations into say LibreOffice, or Abiword without destroying their format - and (this is important!) this company wants the end result to be still editable using MathType. Please any help would be appreciated as I have already spent two days researching and have found nothing yet.

Comment: One can easily copy the `AMSLATEX` math into Mathtype and vice-versa. When copying from Mathtype (Go to Preferences--> cut copy preferences and select the AMSLatex in MATHML or tex ) deselect the  other options include translation and include mathtype data thats all

Comment: But then how can I convert to a .doc or .docx format? Or is that possible at all?

Comment: You're off topic here but according to http://www.mathtype.com/en/products/mathtype/features.htm#mathml_import mathtype can import latex so as long as you keep to basic latex math and not too many fancy packages it should just go in to mathtype

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Do you mean mathtype is not robust enough to import and export AMSMath only basic math functions work ?

Comment: So I type in latex, then import into mathtype, correct? But then (and forgive me if I already stated this) , but how can I take that mathtype file and put it into a doc or docx format so that when I send off a solution, this company (using Windows) can [if needed] edit the Mathtype equation? Or am I just missing something here? Thanks again.

Comment: I believe it's fairly robust, but if you look around this site you may start to believe that a typical latex expression should involve a 3d animated surface plots calculated on the fly using tikz. I don't have the software but any convertor has its limits....

Comment: The point is that if you check that your tex imports into mathtype you can send them the tex, they can import it then edit in mathtype just as if it had bee entered directly in the editor.

Comment: @David Carlisle: That makes sense. But they also want the final solution to be in .doc format and mathtype format - ?is there any way I can do that at all? (I realize this is straying somewhat) Here is what the company actually wants (from their Solution Authoring Guide)--                                              1. Use MS Word 2003 version preferably, and choose 
2003 Document” while saving.
2. For all equations, use MathType.
   Always align MathType objects to the left margin of the Word document.
 So, I guess I need to know i.e. my 'bottom line' is can I do this in Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To say it short: You can't run MS Word starter software on Ubuntu without an virtualiser programm (with installed windows) or wine or other software. As you said, you do not want to install this kind of helping software so the answer is clear: there is no solution to install MS Word Starter on your system.

With LaTeX you can't write a Mathtype and MS Word document, so you have to use the software the company wants to be used. Or to persuade them to use a typogaphical much more better software called LaTeX ...